# webrtcbin leaks socket / file descriptor

Tags: sockets, webrtc, gstreamer

I'm creating a client application where I construct and destroy webrtcbin gstreamer components as the remote pears connect and disconnect. During the ICE negotiation the application opens several ports which is fine.

```
> netstat -aon | findstr 11608
  TCP    10.17.106.41:54009     0.0.0.0:0                   LISTENING       11608
  TCP    127.0.0.1:53981        127.0.0.1:57778             ESTABLISHED     11608
  TCP    192.168.56.1:54012     0.0.0.0:0                   LISTENING       11608
  TCP    [fe80::34:f544:540:20ec%6]:54010  [::]:0           LISTENING       11608
  TCP    [fe80::8618:6e2e:a295:191c%14]:54011  [::]:0       LISTENING       11608
  UDP    10.17.106.41:62525     *:*                                         11608
  UDP    192.168.56.1:62528     *:*                                         11608
  UDP    [fe80::34:f544:540:20ec%6]:62526  *:*                              11608
  UDP    [fe80::8618:6e2e:a295:191c%14]:62527  *:*                          11608
```

when the remote peer disconnects I set the webrtcbin to a GST_STATE_NULL state and according to other sources:

https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/gstreamer/gst-plugins-bad/-/issues/1169

https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/gstreamer/gst-plugins-bad/-/issues/1636

this should free up the ports what have been reserved by webrtcbin.

The problem is it doesn't happen and the file descriptors which describes these port connections gets leaked I guess.

Already tryed to apply the bus flush trick mentioned in the links but it doesn't helped.